# How to integrate a library in my web application built on jsp

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax

I m Trying to integrate a spellchecker library into my application...can anyone suggest me a good tutorial or help me witha few minor and specific details on how to do it....help would be highly appreciated.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more info about the library?

Assuming its a java library it should go to the /WEB-INF/lib folder and you should be able to access it directly from your code.

Comment: Thanks....I was able to get it working by using the same.....